# NullPointerException trying to get an ArrayList

Tags: spring, controller, entity, one-to-many, many-to-one

Why do I get NullPointerException when I call out the method getAll()? The methods readById and createItem work correctly.

ENTITIES:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "goods")
public class Goods {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer goodsId;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "goods", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<OrderDetails> ordersDetails;
    
//getters and setters
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "order_details")
public class OrderDetails {
    
    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(OrderDetails.class);
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer orderId;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "goods_id")
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_WRITE)
    private Goods goods;
    
//getters and setters
}
```

SERVICE:

```
@Service
public class GoodsServiceImpl implements GoodsService {
    
    @Override
    public List<Goods> getAll() {
        return goodsRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Goods readById(int goodsId) {
        return goodsRepository.findById(goodsId).get();
    }

}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
@RestController
public class GoodsRestController {
    
    @GetMapping(value = "")
    public List<Goods> findAllGoods() {
        return goodsService.getAll();
    }
    
    @GetMapping(value = "/{goodsId}")
    public Goods findItemById(@PathVariable Integer goodsId) {
        return goodsService.readById(goodsId);
    }
}
```

The method getAll in orderDetails works. When I try to get all goods I get these in logs:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.List.iterator()" because the return value of "com.example.service_search.model.entity.Goods.getOrdersDetails()" is null

Why is the List ordersDetails in Goods null?